# How to convert unsigned value to byte string

Tags: python

I am looking for a function who do:

```
def unsignedToByteString(size, value):
  // ...
  return output

unsignedToByteString(2, 0x5678) = '\x56\x78'
unsignedToByteString(4,   1234) = '\x00\x00\x04\xd2'
```

Argument:

- size: len of the string
- value: the value to convert to hexadecimal string

Is there any built-in function to do that.
If not how can that be easily done.

Update: I found `chr` function for having a value less than 126 to a hexadecimal character. (I guess i can use that to build a string)

```
chr(0xab) = '\xab'
```

Comment: What research have you done to show there isn't a function that does this? What code have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I did not find any on python official documentation nor in stackoverflow nor in google, this is why I am posting in stackoverflow... I found `chr(0xab) = '\xab'` which can be used but I didn't find any for value more than 255 (1B) which would produce a string.

Comment: What is the `size` variable controlling ? How many pairs of hex digits in the output?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add the explanation, It is the output string size. I will update the ticket

Comment: @Phong: to help you with your terminology: you do not want a "hexadecimal string", ie. something like "deadbeef", you want a simple "byte string" containing the same byte values as your integer. it's hard to explain in a comment, but think about this: in this case "hexadecimal" only comes into play when you _display_ the string.

Comment: Thank for the explanation, I will modify the title to byte string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using `hex` function. It will turn `1234` input into `'0x4d2'` and `0x5678` will stay `'0x5678'`. Then you can use `zfill` method to get it to the required size. And then all is left is to use `decode('hex')` on it. Here is the code:

```
def unsignedToHexaString(size, value):
    output = hex(value)
    output = output[2:].zfill(size*2)
    return output.decode('hex')
```

If your value fits into 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes, you can use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('H', 0x5678)
b'xV'
>>> struct.pack('H', 0xbeef)
b'\xef\xbe'
>>> struct.pack('!H', 0xbeef) # big-endian byte order
b'\xbe\xef'
>>> struct.pack('!L', 0xbeef)
b'\x00\x00\xbe\xef'
```

If you need to encode larger values, you have to split it into smaller chunks yourself. For example, with 128 bits:

```
>>> struct.pack('!QQ', *divmod(0xdeadbeef0cafe0deadbeef, 2**64))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xde\xad\xbe\xef\x0c\xaf\xe0\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

Comment: I have tried this out, and it looks like it is working pretty fine.  I guess `decode('hex')` was the function I was looking for.

Comment: And to check if there is no overflow, I guess you can compare `len(output) == size * 2`

Comment: You actually figured out why i needed that function. I wanted to use struct but the size of the value was quite unconventional (16B) that I needed a conversion function.

Comment: @Phong: you asked the wrong question, then. didn't you?

Comment: @hop: Maybe, but the answer to that question actually solve my problem.

Comment: @Phong: in an inelegant way

Answer (score -1):

As a one-liner:

```py
unsignedToHexaString = lambda s, v: (("%%0%dx" % (s * 2)) % v).decode("hex")
```

Comment: *"the value to convert to hexadecimal string"*, is that so?

Comment: Is there any misunderstanding in my post ? (my output wanted value is '\x12\x34' and not '0x1234')

Comment: @Phong: yes, very much so

Comment: could you fix it for me (or telling me how to fix it ?). I guess my terminology is quite wrong